# Converting jsonb values to array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column of type jsonb called `attributes`.

I have rows with values like -

```
{
    "id1": "something1",
    "id2": "something2",
    "id3": "something3",
}
```

and I want to convert them into -

```
{
    "id1": ["something1"],
    "id2": ["something2"],
    "id3": ["something3"],
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't cross-post, you have posted same question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600260/postgresql-converting-jsonb-values-to-array

Answer (score 1):

You would have to unroll it with `jsonb_to_record` or write a function in plv8,

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
  'id1', jsonb_build_array(id1),
  'id2', jsonb_build_array(id2),
  'id3', jsonb_build_array(id3)
) 
FROM (VALUES ($${
  "id1": "something1",
  "id2": "something2",
  "id3": "something3"
}$$::jsonb)) AS t(j)
CROSS JOIN jsonb_to_record(j)
  AS t2(id1 text, id2 text, id3 text);
```